# How should I parse a POST request message's content in a Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, json, tomcat, servlets, httprequest

I am trying to develop a Java servlet in Tomcat to handle post requests, eventually intending to process files and return said processed files in the response to the client. Based on my searching so far, it seems that the requests I'm going to be handling are given an unusual format. I can suggest alternatives, but I do not have control over the design of the request, which will look as follows:

```
POST /api/0/actions/image HTTP/1.1
Host: <host>.com
Content-Length: <content-length>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<boundary>
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: <user-agent>

--<boundary>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application"

{<authentication_info_as_JSON_object>}
--<boundary>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="inputName"

<inputname>
--<boundary>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="options"

{<options_as_JSON}
--<boundary>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input"; filename="<inputname>"
Content-Type: <content-type>

<file-binary>
--<boundary>--
```

I could parse this request's content as text using regular expressions and standard string processing methods, reconstructing the JSON objects and file(s) I need to handle manually. But that strikes me as a bug-prone and difficult to maintain approach. Are there open source tools out there that can help me process this request in a more structured or standard way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this unusual?

Use [Apache Commons' FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) or equivalent.

If you're on a Servlet 3.0 container, this is baked in, e.g., [HttpServletRequest.getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29)

Comment: Conversation with my colleagues and a lack of results when looking for the answer to this on my own lead me to believe we were doing something weird with these requests. I guess I just wasn't looking in the right place. I'm not sure why, but I've been having a hard time finding what I need in the Tomcat APIs. This is what I was looking for here, so thanks.